# Woocommerce - Hight memory usage when programmatically updating product variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, memory-leaks

I need to programmatically update about 7000 product variations.

I have tried several solutions and best performance I got with this (thanks to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189371/how-to-solve-suspected-memory-issue-in-custom-wordpress-loop):

```
<?php

require_once("wp-load.php");

$dealer_file = json_decode(file_get_contents('file.json'), true);

$args = array(
    'fields'         => 'ids',
    'posts_per_page' => 10, 
    'post_type'      => array('product_variation'),
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
);

$query = new WP_Query;
$paged = 1;
$count = 0;
$total = null;

do {
    $args['no_found_rows'] = isset( $total );
    $args['paged'] = $paged++;

    $post_ids = $query->query( $args );
    update_postmeta_cache( $post_ids );

    if ( ! isset( $total ) )
        $total = $query->found_posts;

    $count += $query->post_count;

    foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
        $sku = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', true );

        if(!empty($sku)) {
            if ( array_key_exists( $sku, $dealer_file ) ) {
                wc_update_product_stock( $post_id, $dealer_file[ $sku ]['stock_info'] );
                echo memory_get_usage(true).'<br>';
            }
            else {
                //Log function
            }
        }

        // Wipe this post's meta from memory
        wp_cache_delete( $post_id, 'posts' );
        wp_cache_delete( $post_id, 'post_meta' );
    }

} while ( $count < $total );

?>
```

With this method I'm using about 600MB of memory (with my code it was 800MB).
I have upgraded to PHP 7.
Is there a way to reduce memory usage further more?

Comment: The only thing I see is add this `define('WP_USE_THEMES', false)` to turn off theme support, if this is run as a background job, then WP wont load up the theme files.  You could do less posts per page, which would probably reduce the memory footprint but take longer.

Comment: Another hit is from `json_decode` you could decode the stuff, save it as an array in a .php file with `<?php return [....];` and then use include.  So you can skip the decoding, this is more useful if your decoding the same thing multiple times (basically cache the data as a PHP array, but that's not always feasible.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix `define('WP_USE_THEMES', false)` didn't have any effect. `json_decode` is used only once, so I thin it will not have any significant impact. Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: How much memory is $dealer_file using?

Comment: @user9372991 8MB of memory. I have just found source of problems. It's `wc_update_product_stock()` Woocommerce function.

Comment: Then I think it is WordPress' object cache. Try wp_cache_flush() inside your loop.

Comment: thanks @user9372991, your comment should be the answer. this NEARLY saved my bacon after a weekend of struggle. It helped greatly, but does not solve the MASSIVE use of resident memory. I'm thinking about using an exec to run a seperate file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was in usage of `wc_update_product_stock()` for updating stock.
Instead of it, now I use:

```
update_post_meta($post_id, '_stock', 'stock_number');
```

Overall usage is bellow 30MB which is excellent IMO.

Comment: This is dangerous as you are now bypassing the WoCommerce API and the action/filter hooks will not be triggered. E.g., stock status is updated when the stock changes. If you directly update the database you can create an inconsistency since other related database fields will not be updated. Using the API insures all related fields are updated.

Comment: The WooCommerce API essentially makes promises to all other plugins and themes. In particular here it promises when the stock of a variation changes the action 'woocommerce_variation_set_stock' will be done. If you bypass the API and directly update the '_stock' database field you have broken this promise. Even if currently nothing is using this promise you may in the future install a plugin that does and it will mysteriously not work. It is a bad practice to bypass the API.

Comment: #realanswerisinthecomments